# How can I make my word rectangle work by making a box from the word

Tags: for-loop, substring, indexof

I am having trouble with stopping this program.

Comment: I have no clue why its not working.Help would be appreciated

Comment: Could you add sample output to your question, please?

Comment: Ok so I revised me question, and gave the output as well

Comment: I think Nick is guiding you well, but IMHO your "incorrect" output is more aesthetically interesting. Maybe you could keep it going until it's all the same letter :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with the code is that you set your index inside of the loop.  There is absolutely no reason why you should be doing this here.  It is usually the case with for loops that you don't want to modify the index inside of the loop.

For reference the code should look like:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
        firstLetter = word.charAt(i);
        word = word.substring(1, word.length());
        System.out.println(firstLetter + word);

        word += firstLetter;
    }
```

This will at least ensure that your loop will end, but it won't necessarily give you the desired output.  Since your question was specific to ending the loop and since this sounds more like a homework assignment, I'll let you do the debugging to make sure you're getting the correct output.

Comment: How can you get the first letter of the word and bring it to the end

Comment: I think you may have missed the last part of my answer.  The point of you doing this assignment is for you to learn how to do the debugging so you can come to the appropriate solution.  From the code snippets you've posted, you know how to modify strings so I'm confident you will be able to figure this out on your own.  It will be more rewarding for you this way.

Comment: Im just making sure , so the word+=firstletter make the word go to the secondletter in the word right.

Comment: After word+=firstletter is done executing, the word variable should have the previous value for word with the firstletter appended to it.  So if word = "OMPUTER" and firstletter was 'C', after running word would be "OMPUTERC".  You should probably look at what firstletter is getting set to.